# Update only one Container via docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Let's say I have a *docker-compose.yml* file containg five apps & I started them via `docker-compose up -d` Now there is an update for **one** of these apps available which I want to use. So I pull this newer image and... how can I stop this one old container **without stopping the four other container**?

- Using `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d` would stop and restart all of my container, so that's wrong.
- Using `docker stop app_1 && docker run app_1` would work but seems "wrong" to me because it's no `docker-compose` command.

So what's the "docker-way" to do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just run `docker-compose up -d` again (without `down` / `stop` / `kill` before).

Initial `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2"

services:
  db1:
    command: mongod
    image: mongo:3.2.4
    ports:
      - "27020:27017"

  db2:
    command: mongod
    image: mongo:3.2.4
    ports:
      - "27021:27017"
```

Update `db2`:

```
version: "2"

services:
  db1:
    command: mongod
    image: mongo:3.2.4
    ports:
      - "27020:27017"

  db2:
    command: mongod
    image: mongo:3.2.6
    ports:
      - "27021:27017"
```

Run `docker-compose up -d` again:

```
Pulling db2 (mongo:3.2.6)...
3.2.6: Pulling from library/mongo
47994b92ab73: Pull complete
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
71b6becd9768: Pull complete
7d5d40f9dc7b: Pull complete
9dc152e647de: Pull complete
3f1f69340f17: Pull complete
82a29b50f1d2: Pull complete
97869c61a050: Pull complete
50aa2bf3bccc: Pull complete
03913f2c5b05: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:29ee114c0ce96494553cd72f18d92935b36778b77bce167fc9962e442d8c7647
Status: Downloaded newer image for mongo:3.2.6
composetest_db1_1 is up-to-date
Recreating composetest_db2_1
```

The last two lines of the output show the expected behavior.

Comment: If I try this I get lots of error messages "Container name in already in use".

Answer (score 42):

There's one use-case where the accepted answer doesn't work:

Say you have 4 containers, with 2 having a new version, and you only want to update/restart ONE of them.

If you simply do `docker-compose up -d` again, this will update both containers.

If you want to target only one specific container, you can do it in two steps:

- Pull all updates: `docker-compose pull` (this will just download the images, not do anything else)
- And then only update the container you want: `docker-compose up -d --no-deps name_of_your_container`

`--no-deps` is important to avoid restarting dependencies of your updated containers by mistake.

Comment: Really appreciate your detailed answer and it helps!

Answer (score 7):

To restart only one container you can simply do:

```
docker-compose up -d --build image-name
```

The output will look like this:

```
Recreating image-name ... done
```

Comment: image-name or service-name? I always thought it was the latter.